# ng-click doesn't fire $mdDialog callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material, and have an action in TasksCtrl that opens a $mdDialog - using the locals property to pass an object that will be modified in DialogCtrl before being sent back to the view.

However, the .then() callbacks do not fire on ng-click. If I hardcode a scope variable that is printed out elsewhere in the dialog, I can see the ng-click changing the value, however the only way to get the .then() to fire is by clicking outside of the modal.

**TasksController (as TasksCtrl)**

```
(function() {

    angular.module('ICP_App')
        .controller('TasksController', function(ToggleService, TasksService, $mdToast, $mdDialog) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.createTaskAttachment = function(ev) {
                $mdDialog.show({
                    controller: 'DialogController',
                    controllerAs: 'DialogCtrl',
                    templateUrl: '../partials/dialogs/create-task-attachment.tmpl.html',
                    locals: {
                        data: vm.selectedTask
                    },
                    parent: angular.element(document.body),
                    targetEvent: ev,
                    clickOutsideToClose:true
                })
                    .then(function(answer) {
                        alert('you submitted');
                    }, function() {
                        alert('you cancelled it');
                    });
            };
        })


})();
```

**DialogController (as DialogCtrl)**

```
(function() {

    angular.module('ICP_App')
        .controller('DialogController', function(data) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.selectedTask = data;
            vm.tempAttachments = [];

             vm.addTempAttachment = function(keypress, type) {

                if (keypress.which === 13) {
                    if (type == 'link') {
                        vm.tempLinkAttachment.category = 'link';
                        vm.tempAttachments.push(vm.tempLinkAttachment);
                        vm.tempLinkAttachment = {};
                    }
                }
             };

        })


})();
```

**And the template file for the $mdDialog**

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Create Attachment" flex-gt-sm="50">
    <form>
        <md-toolbar>

            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <h2>Add New Attachment</h2>
                <span flex></span>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-dialog-content>
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
                <md-tab label="Link">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div layout="row">

                            <div flex>

                                <!-- Add new action -->
                                <div layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row" class="new-entry-line">

                                    <div flex-gt-sm="50">

                                        <md-input-container class="md-block">

                                            <input ng-model="DialogCtrl.tempLinkAttachment.Title" placeholder="Title...">

                                        </md-input-container>

                                    </div>

                                    <div flex-gt-sm="50">

                                        <md-input-container class="md-block">

                                            <input ng-model="DialogCtrl.tempLinkAttachment.Link" placeholder="Link..." ng-keypress="DialogCtrl.addTempAttachment($event, 'link')">

                                        </md-input-container>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div layout="row">
                            <div flex>
                                <md-list>
                                    <md-list-item md-2-line ng-repeat="attachment in DialogCtrl.tempAttachments | filter: {'category': 'link'}">
                                        <md-icon md-svg-icon="content:ic_link_24px"></md-icon>
                                        <p>{{ attachment.title }}</p>
                                    </md-list-item>
                                </md-list>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="File">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div layout="row" layout-align="center">
                                <md-button flex="30" class="md-primary md-raised">Upload</md-button>
                        </div>

                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>


            </md-tabs>

        </md-dialog-content>
        <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
            <md-button ng-click="answer('Not useful')">
                Not Useful
            </md-button>
            <md-button ng-click="answer('Useful')">
                Useful
            </md-button>
        </md-dialog-actions>
    </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak - that's not the issue - I've included the line (there's a lot more code in the controller that isn't relevant and I just didn't copy and paste that line - it's in there now)

Comment: Would you mind creating a runnable example? Either here or in Plunker. It's hard to say anything without tinkering with the code.

Comment: I don't think your setup is correct. DialogController should just be a callback function *not* an app controller. See the example JS - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

Comment: There is an option to use a specific controller - as stated here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog. As I said, clicking outside the modal fires the callback

Comment: I think I understand the problem a bit better now. :-) Let me have a think... I'm not sure using data is the correct way solution.

Comment: OK thanks @camden_kid

Comment: This is how I would pass data from the dialog to the main controller - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QEAmKm?editors=1010#0. Does it help?

Comment: I see - but I'm not using $scope - I'm using 'this' as I'm using controller as syntax. I appreciate that isn't shown in the controller definition - it's defined in my routes. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: @camden_kid I really appreciate the help here - stick that last comment in an answer with a bit of explanation (for others) and I'll happily mark as correct. Not 100% sure if my setup was just incorrect or something was wrong somehwere with the $mdDialog service - but calling $mdDialog close is essentially the answer, and passing the response, which then in turn fires the callback in TasksCtrl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would pass data from the dialog to the main controller - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QEAmKm?editors=1010#0)

`$scope` is used, as mentioned in the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog):

[image]

Note: it is important to set **preserveScope** to true.

JS

```
angular.module('ICP_App',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('TasksController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.createTaskAttachment = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: 'DialogController',
      controllerAs: 'DialogCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'create-task-attachment.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      scope: $scope,
      preserveScope: true,
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true
    })
      .then(function(answer) {
      alert('you submitted - ' + answer);
    }, function() {
      alert('you cancelled it');
    });
  };

  $scope.$watch("vm.selectedTask", function () {
    if (angular.isDefined(vm.selectedTask)) {
      $mdDialog.hide(vm.selectedTask);
    }
  })
})

.controller('DialogController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $scope.vm.selectedTask = answer;
  }
})
```

Comment: But the idea is that I pass the altered data back to TasksCtrl - not start it in one controller and close it in another. Plus the .then() callback should be fired - it does when I click outside of the dialog?

Comment: I think perhaps remove the bit about data being the wrong way - it is clearly shown in the docs as a way to pass data to a controller - rather than passing the whole scope

Comment: @CIvemy As I understand, it is a way to pass data *to* the dialog only. I don't think it can be modified and passed back. I don't use data in my dialogs and pass $scope instead so I could be wrong. Happy to make the edit if you want though.

Comment: You can pass it back in the callback. I think your solution is the best but might be a bit misleading to say the other way is actually incorrect

Comment: @CIvemy Updated answer.